# How to read a dword from a binary file with java?

Tags: java, file-io, dword

I hava a binary file like this :

```
offset | size/type | Description
-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
0x0000 | 28 chars  | zero terminated string
0x001c |  1 dword  | fileoffset of first compressed data block (header size)
0x0020 |  1 dword  | overall size of compressed file
```

I can read the 28 chars as a String. But I don't know how to read a dword and store it as an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataInputStream.readFully() and .readInt(). You may have to do something about the (unspecified) byte order though. If that's an issue, ByteBuffer.getInt(), after setting the appropriate byte order.

Comment: Thank you that helped. Using ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN solved my problem.